# Move up every other line to end of line containing character

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression

I have run two xpath queries piped together to retrieve certain information. However the results came out formatted on separate lines while I want them to be on the same line. For example the lines are like:

```
<id>rd://data1/8b</id>
<name>DM_test1</name>
<id>rd://data2/76f</id>
<name>DM_test_P</name>
```

But I want the line starting with `<name>` to be next to the line ending with `</id>` like this:

```
<id>rd://data1/8b</id><name>DM_test1</name>
```

How can I do this? Is there anywhere in my xpath query that I can add something to make sure there are no spaces? Or is there a regex to move the `<name>` line up?

I have about 20+ lines so I can't do it manually.

Comment: Is your 20+ lines in a sequences?

Comment: yes similar sequence to these 4 lines I posted above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
sed -e '$!N;/\n<name>/s/\n//' file
```

If all your lines are in a sequence, you can use `paste`:

```
paste -sd'\0\n' file
```

Comment: I have tried it but its not doing anything :(

Comment: @user3738022: They both work for me.

Comment: I guess it's not working for me because I am using it within HP's operations orchestration :( i had a similar issue with another sed query that would work every other way except once used within this product..is there an alternate to that doesn't use sed? something constructed like [^/]*$

Comment: Have you tried the `paste` version? - it works, but it will blindly join line 1+2, 3+4, 5+6, 7+8, etc

Comment: yes if i try paste it gives me a "filter processing error, regular expression; input string"

Comment: @user3738022: What shell did you use?

Comment: this one "paste -sd'\0\n' file" gave me the error and the other one doesn't do anything :(